# how to download weblinks using wget which do not end with .html?

Tags: windows, cmd, wget, gnu

I want to download this webpage using wget in Win7 : `http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000`

I am using this command to do this :

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/AT&T_2013-01-29/ http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000
```

I am getting taxostyle not defined, commitmentterm not defined or recognizble method error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes around address

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P "/Downloads/AT&T_2013-01-29/" "http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000"
```

`&` is used as command separator in command window